# Page Renders in Safari but not in Chrome on iPad

Tags: ios, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**Versions**:

- PC OS: Windows 8
- iPad OS: iOS 7.0.2 (11A5901)
- Chrome: 30.0.1599.16
- ExtJS 3.4.0

**Problem**:

I have a web application that relies heavily on Javascript (using the ExtJS framework). It all seems to work as I expect except one page. When browsing this page on my iPad using Safari, the page renders correctly. When in Chrome, I only get the part of the page that doesn't need javascript. However, if I click on the chrome menu and request desktop site then the page loads as intended.

**Things I have tried / searched for**:

1. How to debug this page in Chrome on the iPad. All the articles are either old or say to use Safari (because Chrome and Safari use the same engine?), but the page works in Safari.
2. Setting the agent string in my desktop version of Chrome. The page still loaded correctly.
3. I turned off Javascript in Safari (just to see). Safari then behaved like Chrome.

I'm just looking for a direction to go or something to try. I'm pretty new when it comes to iPad development. But I think that if I could just see what the developer tools show, I can work it out from there. I can't post a link because the site is behind a login.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would also add that using Fiddler was a huge help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to load [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) on your page. This would allow you to log errors and print JavaScript values to the console.